# Проверка вхождения числа в строку

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице хранится строка вида `'1,2,10,12,30'`. Здесь прописываются группы пользователя. Как проверить подходит ли данная группа этому пользователю? Например группа 1 должна подходить для `'1,2,11`' но не для `'11,21'`, поэтому `LIKE` не подходит. Какие еще есть варианты? `11 IN(uedb_specializations)` работает,только если строка начинается с данного числа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое правильное решение - завести таблицу `groups' и там хранить все группы отдельно. Тогда решение становится элементарным.

Неправильное решение обрамить строку запятыми и использовать `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CONCAT(',', groups, ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Comment: ваше неправильное решение работает. С какими проблемами я столкнусь если буду его использовать?

Comment: @WebDev невозможность использовать индексы и, как следствие, **очень** долгий поиск. Плюс вы жестко затачиваетесь на разделитель "запятая" и если где-то встретится "запятая и пробел", то долго будете искать ошибку. Правда от такого, может защитить `RLIKE` и регулярное віражение, но тогда поиск будет работать еще дольше

Comment: насчет скорости, думаю переживем, так как записей там будет штук 100, максимум, кроме того кроме цифр и запятой там не могут быть другие символы, так как все жестко формируется

Answer (score 2):

Это будет работать медленно и печально. Заведите дополнительную таблицу `USER_GROUPS`. В ней должны быть колонки

```
ID | ID_USER | ID_GROUP
```

Потом посадите на нее уникальный индекс по полям ID_USER, ID_GROUP и все у вас будет шикарно работать.

Comment: скорее всего вы правы, но я не могу так поступить, это таблица cms, и я не могу ничего там менять, только обращаться..

Comment: @WebDev либо CMS писали болваны, либо перед вами агрегированный обзор, и где-то лежит таки нормализованная таблица.

Comment: в случае груп, я может и найду такую таблицу, но суть в том, что здесь большинство, где можно выбрать несколько вариантов хранится в таком виде, нужен общий принцип как с этим работать